# Building a delay and loop in cygwin cmdline

Tags: loops, cygwin, delay

I'm trying to build a delay and loop into my cygwin command line. Is this possible and if so, how?

*I don't think I can be more specific without getting into much irrelevant details. However, if you want additional information, do let me know.*

/edit/

I installed default cygwin with some additional stuff: wget most importantly. I am trying to loop a wget commandline each x minutes/hours/days. It is merely logging in to a website.

I am using mintty

/edit2/

Getting the cron package for cygwin since that's more efficient.

Comment: Yes, we need more information.  The default interactive shell is `bash`; are you trying to modify the behavior of the shell itself?  What is this loop supposed to do?  What is it iterating over?

Comment: Well you need to be more specific, because it's not clear what you want. What does "into my command line" mean? Do you want your command prompt to appear after a specific delay each time you press enter, or where should this delay appear? You need add a concrete example to your question.

Comment: @Keith I added some more information.

Comment: @Casper I added some more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as a shell script, or write this on the bash command prompt to perform an infinite loop with a 1 second delay:

```
while true; do echo "hello"; sleep 1; done
```

So with wget you would do:

```
while true; do wget ...; sleep 1; done
```

To add more delay just change the number after `sleep`.